# Validar RadioButton com jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Gostaria de fazer uma validação via jQuery, para saber se o cliente selecionou algum `RadioButton`

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/6k8nG/1/)**

Ele exibe um alert caso não tenha selecionado, mas ele ainda envia (submited), não deveria.

HTML

```
 <table id="RadioButtonList1" cellspacing="15" cellpadding="15">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="RadioButtonList1_0" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList1" value="1" /><label for="RadioButtonList1_0">opc 01</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="RadioButtonList1_1" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList1" value="2" /><label for="RadioButtonList1_1">opc 02</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="RadioButtonList1_2" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList1" value="3" /><label for="RadioButtonList1_2">opc 03</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="RadioButtonList1_3" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList1" value="4" /><label for="RadioButtonList1_3">opc 04</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="RadioButtonList1_4" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList1" value="5" /><label for="RadioButtonList1_4">opc 5</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Votar" id="Button1" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

JS

```
 jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#Button1').bind('click',checkRadio);
 })

 function checkRadio() {
    var isChecked = jQuery("input[name=fileType]:checked").val();
    var booleanVlaueIsChecked = false;
    if (!isChecked) {
        booleanVlaueIsChecked = true;
        alert('Selecione algum logotipo');
    }
 }
```

Comment: Faltou dar `preventDefault` no evento gerado pelo click quando não quiser submeter o formulário. Além disso precisa declarar o evento como parâmetro da função.

Comment: Adicionei partes relevantes do código na pergunta, para facilitar o entendimento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode colocar um `return false` depois do `alert`:

```
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('#Button1').bind('click',checkRadio);
});

function checkRadio() {
   var isChecked = jQuery("input[name=RadioButtonList1]:checked").val();
   var booleanVlaueIsChecked = false;
   if (!isChecked) {
       booleanVlaueIsChecked = true;
       alert('Selecione algum logotipo');
       return false;
   }
}
```

Tem mais um erro no script, o nome do campo

```
var isChecked = jQuery("input[name=fileType]:checked").val();
```

Altere para

```
var isChecked = jQuery("input[name=RadioButtonList1]:checked").val();
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6k8nG/5/)**

Comment: Esta solução funcionou para o meu caso também estava com a mesma dificuldade em validar os RadioButton no meu caso também faltou dar um Return false na função.

Answer (score 1):

Teste assim:

```
 jQuery(function () {
     jQuery('#form1').on('submit', checkRadio);
 })

 function checkRadio() {
     var isChecked = jQuery("input[name=fileType]:checked").val();

     var booleanVlaueIsChecked = false;
     if (!isChecked) {
         booleanVlaueIsChecked = true;
         alert('Selecione algum logotipo');
         return false;
     }
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6xs5x/1/

A diferença é que agora eu escuto o `submit` da form e no caso de dar erro faço `return false;`

Comment: +1 - minha resposta estava pronta, por isso publiquei :)

Comment: @abfurlan, obrigado. A sua resposta é boa também, porem eu prefiro ter certeza que é no `form submit`, não vá o botão ser carregado com teclado.